# WinForm Databound Checkbox Value

Tags: c#, winforms

I get an exception when my databound checkbox is confronted with a null value:

```
{"Cannot bind to the property or column boolValue on the  DataSource.\r\nParameter name: dataMember"}
```

Is there a way to have the checkbox default to unchecked on a null value. I have looked in the databinding properties and on MSDN but can not find anything that seems relevant

Comment: That appears to be a different problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Binding.NullValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.nullvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property for that. But make sure you also set [`Binding.FormattingEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.formattingenabled(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `true`.

For instance, something like this:

```
var dataSource = ...;
checkBox.DataBindings.Add("Checked", dataSource, "{PropertyName}",
    true, // formattingEnabled
    DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged,
    false // nullValue
);
```